# Is there a way to specify fields to receive from Shopify REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, shopify

so I have a backend code that requests products from shopify through ADMIN API. The code works fine, the problem is, shopify returns an array `products` but with a lot of nested attributes inside. Is there a way I can request specific attributes i.e `title, price,` etc only specific fields?

Here is my code which works perfectly:

```
export const getProducts = expressAsyncHandler(async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/products.json`, {
            headers: {
                "X-Shopify-Access-Token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
            }
        });
        const products = response.data; //.products;
        res.json(products);
        
    } catch (error) {
        throw new CustomAppError(500, error)
    }
});
```

This is some of what shopify return through postman

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 6114761277630,
            "title": "2-Ply Gilead Facemask - Millitary Green / Print",
            "body_html": "<p data-mce-fragment=\"1\">Made in Kenya.<br data-mce-fragment=\"1\"></p>\n<p data-mce-fragment=\"1\">Wholesale and bulk order prices available on request for quantities over 10 pieces. </p>\n<p data-mce-fragment=\"1\">Call 0740821990 for more details. </p>",
            "vendor": "UHURU MARKET",
            "product_type": "ACCESSORIES",
            "created_at": "2020-12-09T13:20:14+03:00",
            "handle": "gilead-facemask-millitary-print",
            "updated_at": "2023-09-12T17:41:55+03:00",
            "published_at": null,
            "template_suffix": "",
            "published_scope": "web",
            "tags": "ACCESSORIES, express, EXPRESS SHIPPING, FACE MASK, FACE MASKS, GILEAD, KIDS, MEN, old products, OLDDEVPROD, UHURU MARKET, WOMEN",
            "status": "active",
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Product/6114761277630",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "id": 37678735687870,
                    "product_id": 6114761277630,
                    "title": "MILLITARY GREEN / F / UM00309",
                    "price": "9.00",
                    "sku": "5fa6528db905e",
                    "position": 1,
                    "inventory_policy": "deny",
                    "compare_at_price": "10.00",
                    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                    "inventory_management": "shopify",
                    "option1": "MILLITARY GREEN",
                    "option2": "F",
                    "option3": "UM00309",
                    "created_at": "2020-12-09T13:20:14+03:00",
                    "updated_at": "2023-09-12T12:05:30+03:00",
                    "taxable": true,
                    "barcode": "161365",
                    "grams": 0,
                    "image_id": null,
                    "weight": 0,
                    "weight_unit": "kg",
                    "inventory_item_id": 39771820720318,
                    "inventory_quantity": 1,
                    "old_inventory_quantity": 1,
                    "requires_shipping": true,
                    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/37678735687870"
                },
                {
                    "id": 42072972296382,
                    "product_id": 6114761277630,
                    "title": "Yellow / L / Lnvwpijeoj",
                    "price": "9.00",
                    "sku": "",
                    "position": 2,
                    "inventory_policy": "deny",
                    "compare_at_price": "10.00",
                    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                    "inventory_management": "shopify",
                    "option1": "Yellow",
                    "option2": "L",
}
]
}
```

please help me with a technique so I can map through products efficiently

Answer (score 0):

> fields
> Return only certain fields specified by a comma-separated list of field names.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/product#get-products?ids=632910392,921728736

```js
const respFields = ["title", "price"];

const fields = respFields.join(",");


const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/products.json?fields=${fields}`, {
            headers: {
                "X-Shopify-Access-Token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
            }
        });
```

Comment: what if the Value I want to access is inside another array? for example variants is an array nested inside products.

Comment: the docs don't stipulate which fields are available for this query parameter.  Give it a try and see if it works.  They only provide an example as I've shown